# Unable to add button to lightning:datatable for every record in aura

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning, aura

I was trying to create aura component to display contact details as a `lightning:datatable` and a button for every row such that on clicking that button it should display contact details like a pop-up, I was able to create a button, but on-click function is not working, please let me know where I did mistake

**Aura Component:(Name of the compoent : taskThree)**

```
<aura:component controller="auraThree"
implements="force:appHostable, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, flexipage:availableForRecordHome, force:hasRecordId, force:lightningQuickAction"
access="global">
<aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<!--aura:attribute name="Account" type="Account"/-->
<aura:attribute name="Contacts" type="Contact" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.fetchcont }"/>
<!--force:recordData aura:id="accountRecord"
                  recordId="{! v.recordId }"
                  targetFields="{v.Account}"
                  layoutType="FULL"/-->

<lightning:datatable data="{! v.Contacts }"
                     columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
                     keyField="Id"
                     hideCheckboxColumn="true">
</lightning:datatable>
</aura:component>
```

**Aura Controller JS:**

```
({
  fetchcont: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.mycolumns", [
      { label: "Contact Id", fieldName: "Id", type: "String" },
      { label: "Contact Name", fieldName: "Name", type: "text" },
      { label: "Account Name", fieldName: "AccountId", type: "text" },
      { label: "Contact Phone", fieldName: "Phone", type: "phone" },
      {
        label: "view",
        type: "button",
        initialWidth: 135,
        typeAttributes: {
          label: "view Details",
          name: "view_details",
          title: "click to view Details"
        }
      }
    ]);
    var action = component.get("c.fetchContacts");

    action.setParams({
      recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      component.set("v.Contacts", response.getReturnValue());
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
  handleClick: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    alert("You clicked: " + event.getSource().get("v.label"));
  }
});
```

**Apex class:**

```
public class auraThree {
  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<Contact> fetchContacts(Id recordId) {
    List<Contact> contList = [SELECT ID, Name, Account.Name, Phone FROM Contact];

    return contList;
  }
}
```

**Aura Application:**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <c:taskThree/>
</aura:application>
```

[image: issue example]

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It seems that the "handleClick" function is not called when the "view Details" button is clicked. To fix this, you can add an "onrowaction" attribute to the lightning:datatable component and set its value to the name of the function to be called when a row action occurs.

Here's the updated code for the Aura Component and Controller:

Aura Component:

```
<aura:component controller="auraThree"
implements="force:appHostable, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes, flexipage:availableForRecordHome, force:hasRecordId, force:lightningQuickAction"
access="global">
<aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />

<!--aura:attribute name="Account" type="Account"/-->
<aura:attribute name="Contacts" type="Contact" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{! this }" action="{! c.fetchcont }"/>

<!--force:recordData aura:id="accountRecord"
                  recordId="{! v.recordId }"
                  targetFields="{v.Account}"
                  layoutType="FULL"/-->
<lightning:datatable data="{! v.Contacts }"
columns="{! v.mycolumns }"
keyField="Id"
hideCheckboxColumn="true"
onrowaction="{!c.handleRowAction}">
</lightning:datatable>
</aura:component>
```

Aura Controller JS:

```
({
fetchcont: function(component, event, helper) {
component.set("v.mycolumns", [
{ label: "Contact Id", fieldName: "Id", type: "String" },
{ label: "Contact Name", fieldName: "Name", type: "text" },
{ label: "Account Name", fieldName: "AccountId", type: "text" },
{ label: "Contact Phone", fieldName: "Phone", type: "phone" },
{
label: "view",
type: "button",
initialWidth: 135,
typeAttributes: {
label: "view Details",
name: "view_details",
title: "click to view Details"
}
}
]);
var action = component.get("c.fetchContacts");

kotlin
action.setParams({
  recordId: component.get("v.recordId")
});
action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
  component.set("v.Contacts", response.getReturnValue());
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);

},
handleRowAction: function(cmp, event, helper) {
var action = event.getParam("action");
var row = event.getParam("row");
if (action.name === "view_details") {
alert("Contact Name: " + row.Name + "\nAccount Name: " + row.Account.Name + "\nPhone: " + row.Phone);
}
}
});
```

In the updated code, we have added an "onrowaction" attribute to the lightning:datatable component, which is set to the name of the "handleRowAction" function defined in the controller. This function retrieves the action and row details from the event parameter and checks if the action is "view_details". If it is, it displays the contact details in an alert message.